# How do I underline text using FDPF in PHP?

Tags: php, fpdf, underline

I'm trying to make my text underlined in `FPDF` but it seems to be impossible... I'm not using HTML. I'm using an `DejaVu` unicode font, which supports UTF-8, and also its my first time working with the FPDF.

Is that even possible? Please give me some solutions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

```
$fpdf->SetFont('Dejavu','U'); //Where "U" means underline.
```

See also (in german) http://www.fpdf.de/funktionsreferenz/?funktion=SetFont

See also (in english) http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setfont.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately the `arial` doesn't support a special characters, and I'm forced to use the `Dejavu` font to support `unicode`.

Comment: `$fpdf->SetFont('','U');` was enough. Thanks !

Comment: these functions seem no longer available (?)

Comment: I did not look into the code, but in the online documentation it is still there. Why do you think so?